# Dependency between two async actions in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

My Home.vue needs two async actions:

```
created() {
  this.$store.dispatch('GET_LATEST_POLL');
  this.$store.dispatch('INIT_STREAM');
},
```

This is their Vuex implementation:

```
GET_LATEST_POLL: async (context) => {
  const pollData = await axios.get(`${BFF_ENDPOINT}/polls/last`, getAuthHeader(context));
  const item = pollData.data.data;
  context.commit('SET_LATEST_POLL', item);
},

INIT_STREAM: async (context) => {
  const streamData = await axios.get(`${API_ENDPOINT}/polls/?obd=date`, getAuthHeader(context));
  const items = streamData.data.data;
  items.filter(item => item._id !== context.state.latestPoll._id);
  context.commit('SET_STREAM', items);
},
```

I realized there is a dependency of INIT_STREAM to LATEST_POLL on `context.state.latestPoll`. I do not want to serialize both actions, I want they both talk to the backend paralelly. But then I need INIT_STREAM to wait for the LATEST_POLL result.

How can I achieve it? Do I have to merge the logic into the single action which fires two promises and then `await Promise.all([latestPoll, items])`? Is this correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to have a single action dispatched from your component which in turn dispatches other 2 actions which do not mutate anything.

```
LatestPollAndStreamAction: async (context) => {
    let pollDataRequest = axios.get(...);
    let streamDataRequest = axios.get(...);
    Promise.all(pollDataRequest , streamDataRequest).then(([latestPoll, items]) => {
        const pollItem = latestPoll.data.data;
        context.commit('SET_LATEST_POLL', pollItem);
        //logic for the other commit
        const streamItems = streamData.data.data;
        streamItems.filter(item => item._id !== context.state.latestPoll._id);
        context.commit('SET_STREAM', streamItems);
    })
}
```

This will ensure that both of your requests are fired in parallel and once you have the result from both using do the commits in desired order.

PS: The code is not tested but is just you give a gist of the desired approach

Comment: Thanks, I meant it this way.

Answer (score 1):

As I interpreted the question, you were suggesting creating a third action that merged the two actions. That approach sounds okay, but I think you could also adjust INIT_STREAM to make the calls in parallel. You need to:

1. Make sure GET_LATEST_POLL returns its promise.
2. Dispatch the action to GET_LATEST_POLL from INIT_STREAM, but don't `await` the result - just store the return value as `const getLatestPollPromise`.
3. Make the axios call for `const streamData = await axios.get...` but again, change it from await to `const streamDataPromise = axios.get...`
4. Use `await Promise.all([getLatestPollPromise, streamDataPromise])` like you proposed in the question.

If INIT_STREAM always needs latestPoll, I see no need for a third action as that qualifies as a leaky abstraction and will probably confuse other developers.

Comment: I meant merging both actions into single action. Upvoted.

Comment: If you can distill them down to one action, that seems like a good idea - it's a simpler api. But if `GET_LATEST_POLL` will be needed later, then keep them as two. It's like public vs private code. I consider each action to be like a public method. Only make public what you need to.

Comment: My intention is to build Instagram like stream of objects when one item has a prominent place and I do not need it repeated in the stream. So I want to  filter it out from found data. I worry that things get complicated once I will start implementing fetch new page of records.

Comment: That's a good thing to be worried about. Keep it as simple and well-crafted as you can at each step, adding complexity only when it is necessary. And write unit tests :-)